# NPE when instantiating WS-Client

Tags: web-services, jboss

When I instantiate may Webservice Client in Jboss 4.2.3 I get the following Exception.

Looks like the Webservice client is just loading the WSDL from classpath.

The Problem occures wehn Jboss tries to open the following URL: "file:/C:/ta30/progs/JBoss423_EntwicklerVersion/jboss-4.2.3.GA.ZPV/server/default/tmp/jbossws/JBossWS_xx.xx.xx_namespace_xxx-xx_xxx_20040201#967130196328257771.xsd"

Does anyone know what could be the reason for that problem ??

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.JavaToXSD.parseSchema(JavaToXSD.java:179)
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDL11Reader.processTypes(WSDL11Reader.java:401)
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDL11Reader.processDefinition(WSDL11Reader.java:178)
    at org.jboss.ws.tools.wsdl.WSDLDefinitionsFactory.parse(WSDLDefinitionsFactory.java:128)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.ServiceMetaData.getWsdlDefinitions(ServiceMetaData.java:295)
    at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.buildMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:86)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.<init>(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:140)
    at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:64)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:81)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the '#' in the namespace. That produced an URL that could not be processes by jboss.